# understanding nested python dict comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I am getting along with dict comprehensions and trying to understand how the below 2 dict comprehensions work:

```
select_vals = ['name', 'pay']
test_dict = {'data': [{'name': 'John', 'city': 'NYC', 'pay': 70000}, {'name': 'Mike', 'city': 'NYC', 'pay': 80000}, {'name': 'Kate', 'city': 'Houston', 'pay': 65000}]}
```

```
dict_comp1 = [{key: item[key] for key in select_vals } for item in test_dict['data']  if item['pay'] > 65000 ]
```

The above line gets me
`[{'name': 'John', 'pay': 70000}, {'name': 'Mike', 'pay': 80000}]`

```
dict_comp2 = [{key: item[key]} for key in select_vals  for item in test_dict['data']  if item['pay'] > 65000 ]
```

The above line gets me
`[{'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Mike'}, {'pay': 70000}, {'pay': 80000}]`

How does the two o/ps vary when written in a for loop ? When I  execute in a for loop

```
dict_comp3 = []
for key in select_vals:
    for item in test_dict['data']:
        if item['pay'] > 65000:
            dict_comp3.append({key: item[key]})

print(dict_comp3)
```

The above line gets me same as dict_comp2
`[{'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Mike'}, {'pay': 70000}, {'pay': 80000}]`

How do I get the o/p as dict_comp1 in a for loop ?

Comment: Only the first one contains a dict comprehension. Both are list comprehensions, the first contains a dictionary comprehension, the other doesnt

Comment: So, `{key: item[key] for key in select_vals }` is a dictionary comprehension. `{key: item[key]}` is not

Comment: indeed. they are list comprehensions, I extract the list from the initial dict object. still trying to understand in which order  the for loops are called. guess the answer from Paaksing clarifies it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The select vals iteration should be the inner one

```py
result = []
for item in test_dict['data']:
    if item['pay'] > 65000:
        aux = {}
        for key in select_vals:
            aux[key] = item[key]
        result.append(aux)
```